# Cannot create file \\server\printer

Tags: windows, printing, windows-7, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I have a module in vfp9 running under windows 7 32bits, this module prints in a local printer using the command COPY FILE file.txt TO \\server\printer, locally works fine, but in other pc of the network doesn't work, the error cannot create file \\server\printer shows.
In windows xp, this works fine, but in windows 7 not, I  guess is a permission, wich one? where I can find information about this? I disabed the option "disable sharing with password protection" in advanced config of network and I can see all the shared resources, disks and printers.
I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

That's a very 'legacy' way of printing and I wouldn't rely on it. If you have to do it this way, try redirecting an LPT port and then copying to the LPT port. At a CMD prompt:

```
net use lpt3 \\server\printer /yes
```

Then in your application

```
copy file file.txt to lpt3
```

Comment: Same error "Cannot create file \\.\lpt3" in this case the error adds '\\.\' before lpt3. The command NET USE lpt \\server\printer /persistent:yes its ok, no errors. When I try to use gives the error.

Comment: if I try from the command prompt "type archive.txt >lpt3" the error "Access deny" appear.

Comment: OK you need to do this with the report designer, and set printer to\report form to printer I think. You are bypassing the Windows spooler in what you're doing, and that's not guaranteed to work.